# Why does my GLFW window become unresponsive if I less frequently do my draw loop?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

main.cpp:

```cpp
    while(!display.shouldClose()) {
        if(display.checkCycle()) {
            console.oneCycle();
            if(console.drawFlag) {
                display.loop();
                console.drawFlag = false;
            }
        }
        if(display.checkTimer()) {
            console.updateTimers();
        }
    }
```

renderer.hpp:

```cpp
        void loop() {
            glClearColor(0.11f, 0.11f, 0.11f, 1.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            projectionMatrix(&shader, window);
            for(int h = 0; h < 32; h++) {
                for (int w = 0; w < 64; w++) {
                    if (screen->getPixel(w, h) == 1) {
                        shader.setVec2("position", (float)w, (float)h);
                        drawer.draw(va, &shader, 6);
                    }
                }
            }

            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
```

I was attempting to create a chip-8 emulator where the display of the emulator is only updated once it's told to do so by the 'draw flag'. However, whenever I put the `display.loop()` inside of the check for the draw flag, my window seems to become unresponsive. I can't click the red-x on the top left of the window, and my mouse just becomes a spinning rainbow (Since I am on a MacOS device). However, if I put the `display.loop()` outside of the `if(console.drawFlag)...` statement, this behavior goes away, but in doing so the emulation becomes a lot slower and choppier.

Why does putting the draw loop inside of the check for the draw flag lead to this weird unresponsive window behavior?

How do I fix this behavior without sacrificing the speed of my code?

Edit:
I did try to call glfwPollEvents() outside of the draw flag check, but this did nothing.

```cpp
        void pollEvents() {
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
```

```cpp
...
while(!display.shouldClose()) {
    display.pollEvents();
    if(display.checkCycle()) {
...
```

I did keep the glfwPollEvents() in the draw loop too, I'm not sure if this changes anything.

Also, when I ran a rom that activated the draw flag very often, this bug didn't happen.

Comment: Have you tried separating the drawing and the polling? In this case, maybe just put the `glfwPollEvents` call outside.

Comment: @Nelfeal I have tried that, but it didn't fix anything. I will edit my question to show how exactly I attempted to fix it.